# Is attending (and presenting at) a summit taken as an "honor'' in a CV elevating the chance for tenure-track applications?

Tags: cv, assistant-professor

I've been selected by my school and an external committee to attend this-year version of [this summit](https://www.nrf.gov.sg/gyss/home). As far as I've been informed up to now, the agenda is attending a bunch of interviews with both scientists and non-scientists to broadcast my research (panelists are supposed to be some Nobel Laureates).
To me, the only potential motivation to attend it would be the case based on which such attendance will be considered as an *honor* in my CV (something similar to, or even more significant than, what a "best paper award in X conference" does bring to mind). Namely by honor, I literally mean whatever may make my CV fancier than before to entice typical admission committees assessing assistant professorship applications. Additionally, I have to pay half of the commutation cost which is a great repulsive factor if this summit really wouldn't make any sensible impact on my future chance to hunt a tenure-track position.

All in all, would a "presenter at summit X" add anything big to my CV (considering I've some scholarships, an IEEE thesis title, a best paper award, etc.)?

Comment: The only potential motivation to attend a conference full of Nobel laureates and others with similar awards in their careers is to pad your CV? I'd hope you go to a conference to share your research and learn what others are working on. If it's only to pad a CV then it doesn't seem to be a very well-designed conference.

Comment: @BryanKrause My school is a pretty famous one which regularly hosts such gurus, so I can locally catch them time-to-time without paying 1000 Euros to travel there. By the way, I do NOT seek "padding" but "improving" my CV. You may note that if I wanted to pad, I would attend there and put that "presenter at the summit X" entry in my CV without bothering myself asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this strongly depends on the field.

In pure mathematics, I think *nobody* would be the slightest impressed by "represented my university in the future research leader summit, which managed to heap 25 nobel laureates into a big pile". It might even have a slightly silly and vain vibe (whereas everyone would be ecstatic about an invited talk at the ICM).

But this could be completely different in other fields; so I think your best guess is to trust the opinions and reactions of the (senior) colleagues in your field.

Answer (score 2):

I would think of it the same as any other conference presentation.  Ask your colleagues, supervisors, mentors, etc, how well they regard this particular conference, and whether they think it is worth your time to attend and present.  But you need to get advice from people who know you and are in your field.

The fact that this conference happens to be called a "summit" doesn't change any of that.

Comment: My supervisor's like so-so, and the rest of my colleagues have no idea about it's potential impact. My field is robotics, yet the summit includes presenters from various STEM disciplines.

Comment: Well, multidisciplinary conferences are certainly a thing.  But if your supervisor / colleagues aren't impressed by it, it seems safe to say that search committees reading your CV won't be impressed either.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would also consider the connections that you might be able to create at such a venue. If you get the chance to present before nobel laureates, it might just happen that they like your work and know of an open position at their home university.

The more powerful people know your work, your name and your face, the better. There are many ways to land a good position, and sometimes the deciding factor actually is who you went to have dinner with *-after-* the conference.

So my answer is: go, talk to as many people as possible , and present what you are working on.